# Improving join query postgresql/postgis

Tags: sql, postgresql, query-performance

I believe postgresql can be faster dealing with my query but every attempt to modify it makes it slower!

I have 2 tables:

- statistics (id, field1, [...], field10)
- geometry (id, geom)

I created indexes on :

- statistics.id
- geometry.id
- geometry (st_x(st_centroid(st_transform(geom, 2154))), st_y(st_centroid(st_transform(geom, 2154))))

Here is the query

```
EXPLAIN ANALYZE SELECT 
statistics.*,
st_x(st_centroid(st_transform(geometry.geom, 2154))) AS x,
st_y(st_centroid(st_transform(geometry.geom, 2154))) AS y

FROM statistics
 JOIN geometry ON statistics.id = geometry.id 

WHERE statistics.id not like '97%';
```

Here is the result

```
Hash Join  (cost=1294.66..5158.10 rows=36593 width=342) (actual time=20.788..1085.257 rows=36552 loops=1)
Hash Cond: (geometry.id = (statistics.id)::text)
->  Seq Scan on geometry  (cost=0.00..2445.46 rows=36593 width=279) (actual time=0.010..25.271 rows=36597 loops=1)
    Filter: (id !~~ '97%'::text)
->  Hash  (cost=835.96..835.96 rows=36696 width=69) (actual time=19.892..19.892 rows=36696 loops=1)
    Buckets: 4096  Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 3780kB
    ->  Seq Scan on statistics  (cost=0.00..835.96 rows=36696 width=69) (actual time=0.005..6.871 rows=36696 loops=1)
Planning time: 0.401 ms
Execution time: 1088.612 ms
```

The most expensive operation is the Hash Join. How would you reorganise there query to get a better result?

Below is the schema of the tables

```
CREATE TABLE "statistics" (
    "REG" integer,
    "DEP" character varying(10),
    "COM" character varying(50),
    "D03" integer,
    "D04" integer,
    "D05" integer,
    "D06" integer,
    "D07" integer,
    "D08" integer,
    "D09" integer,
    "D10" integer,
    "D11" integer,
    "D12" integer,
    "D13" integer,
    "id" text
);

CREATE TABLE geometry (  
    id text NOT NULL,
    id_geo numeric(10,0),
    cm_code character varying(3),
    name character varying(50),
    status character varying(20),
    lat integer,
    long integer,
    lat_centroid integer,
    long_centroid integer,
    z_ smallint,
    area numeric(10,0),
    population double precision,
    code_ct character varying(2),
    code_r character varying(1),
    code_dp character varying(2),
    name_dp character varying(30),
    code_rg character varying(2),
    geom geometry(MultiPolygon,4326),
    x real,
    y real
);
```

There is about 40 000 rows in each table

The indexes have been created as follow

```
CREATE INDEX statistics_id_idx ON public.statistics USING btree (id COLLATE pg_catalog."default");
CREATE INDEX geometry_geom_idx ON public.geometry USING gist (geom);
CREATE INDEX geometry_id_gin2 ON public.geometry  USING gin (id COLLATE pg_catalog."default" gin_trgm_ops);
```

for information I have tried different indexes (btree & gin)  on geometry_id & statistics_id.

Comment: Size of each table? The only problem I see is the `like` and `geometry.id` is different type of `statistics.id` ?? I dont understand your geometry index. for st_x. That wont help for that select.

Comment: each table has 36582 rows

Comment: The tables don't have a primary key, so a hashjoin is the best you can get. (also: using a text field for an id might be sub-optimal)

Comment: @wildplasser there is a primary on the id of each table. However the I get the hash join.

Comment: How could I know that? You did not put that in your table definitions. BTW: for small tables there is nothing wrong with a hash join.

Comment: Please put the index definition as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I dont see any problem with your query.

Things to check

- `(geometry.id = (statistics.id)::text)` are both field same data type?
- `WHERE statistics.id not like '97%';` . `LIKE '%me'` will never use an index, but `LIKE 'me%'` can possibly use an index. [Why doesnt use index?](http://www.postgresonline.com/journal/archives/78-Why-is-my-index-not-being-used.html)
- `st_x(st_centroid(st_transform(geometry.geom, 2154))) AS x,` is a function, and that take time. Need to transform coordinate and then extract a value. You are better if calculate that value and store it in a field.
- Your geometry index doesn't have any impact on this query, because you are calculating a value not searching for something.
- If you want perfom geography search that isnt the right index neither. But we can talk about that later

Things to try

First the `where like`.

```
SELECT *
FROM statistics
WHERE statistics.id not like '97%';
```

Then just the `join`

```
SELECT statistics.*,
       geometry.geom
FROM statistics
JOIN geometry ON statistics.id = geometry.id
```

Then join + st_x

```
SELECT statistics.*,
       st_x(st_centroid(st_transform(geometry.geom, 2154))) AS x,
       st_y(st_centroid(st_transform(geometry.geom, 2154))) AS y
FROM statistics
JOIN geometry ON statistics.id = geometry.id
```

Then create the precalculate `x, y` column in `geometry` table

```
SELECT statistics.*,
       geometry.x,
       geometry.y,
FROM statistics
JOIN geometry ON statistics.id = geometry.id
```

Then join + st_x + `where like` and join + geometry.xy + `where like`

Compare time between each steps to check where is taking the most time.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. Will try what you suggested @Juan Carlos Oropeza

Comment: Transforming the coordinates to store them in the geometry table (x and y) did the trick! I divided the time by 10. The query now runs at 100ms ! Thanks @Juan Carlos Oropeza .

Comment: However when I run the query for real it still takes 5 seconds to run which is better than 6... but I expected a better result.

Comment: Then there is still something wrong doesnt make sense  a query be that slow. I do query with 10 millions rows in ms. Can you edit your post with the table schema? Unless you have slow drives or bad memory setup.

Comment: Ok @Juan Carlos Oropeza. So it is not quite right that pg spend that much time.

Comment: Yes, 5 sec for 35k row is too much

Comment: I have run the query using the command line on the server and I get 230ms. Does it mean that when I query the server from my pc (which is on lan) using pgAdmin3 there is about 4 seconds wasted somewhere which are not imputed to postgres?

Comment: That make more sense than slow query. Looks like you will need do more testing.